# noUiSlider - styling of a specific slider

Tags: css, nouislider

I am currently styling my noUiSlider tooltips with this selector:

`.noUi-vertical .noUi-handle .noUi-tooltip{...}`

I have multiple vertical sliders which i want to style separately, and I am not able to target only a specific slider. This might be trivial to some, so no such question has been asked so far.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sliders have `id`s, you can style them using that id:

```
// Given <div id="my-slider"></div>
#my-slider.noUi-vertical { /* ... */ }
```